# Building nginx from source error

Tags: nginx

I try to build and install nginx from source, everything seems ok but when i try to config the nginx source before build Im getting error. Im using ubuntu 18.04.1 LT, my config command

```
./configure --prefix=/etc/nginx \
        --sbin-path=/usr/sbin/nginx \
        --conf-path=/etc/nginx/nginx.conf \
        --error-log-path=/var/log/nginx/error.log \
        --pid-path=/var/run/nginx.pid \
        --lock-path=/var/run/nginx.lock \
        --user=nginx \
        --group=nginx \
        --build=Ubuntu \
        --builddir=nginx-1.9.9 \
        --with-select_module \
        --with-poll_module \
        --with-threads \
        --with-file-aio \
        --with-http_ssl_module \
        --with-http_v2_module \
        --with-http_realip_module \
        --with-http_addition_module \
        --with-http_xslt_module=dynamic \
        --with-http_image_filter_module=dynamic \
        --with-http_geoip_module=dynamic \
        --with-http_sub_module \
        --with-http_dav_module \
        --with-http_flv_module \
        --with-http_mp4_module \
        --with-http_gunzip_module \
        --with-http_gzip_static_module \
        --with-http_auth_request_module \
        --with-http_random_index_module \
        --with-http_secure_link_module \
        --with-http_degradation_module \
        --with-http_slice_module \
        --with-http_stub_status_module \
        --with-http_perl_module=dynamic \
        --with-perl_modules_path=/usr/share/perl/5.26.1 \
        --with-perl=/usr/bin/perl \
        --http-log-path=/var/log/nginx/access.log \
        --http-client-body-temp-path=/var/cache/nginx/client_temp \
        --http-proxy-temp-path=/var/cache/nginx/proxy_temp \
        --http-fastcgi-temp-path=/var/cache/nginx/fastcgi_temp \
        --http-uwsgi-temp-path=/var/cache/nginx/uwsgi_temp \
        --http-scgi-temp-path=/var/cache/nginx/scgi_temp \
        --with-mail=dynamic \
        --with-mail_ssl_module \
        --with-stream=dynamic \
        --with-stream_ssl_module \
        --with-stream_realip_module \
        --with-stream_geoip_module=dynamic \
        --with-stream_ssl_preread_module \
        --with-compat \
        --with-pcre=../pcre-8.42 \
        --with-pcre-jit \
        --with-zlib=../zlib-1.2.11 \
        --with-openssl=../openssl-1.1.0h \
        --with-openssl-opt=no-nextprotoneg \
        --with-debug \
        --modules-path=/usr/lib/nginx/modules \
```

Error im getiing is `./configure: error: invalid option "--with-http_xslt_module=dynamic"`

Comment: Have you tried to remove the invalid option? Is there any guide you are following (maybe the one at https://www.vultr.com/docs/how-to-compile-nginx-from-source-on-ubuntu-16-04)? Please include a link to it.

Comment: thanx @Melebius, that option is not invalid according to nginx documentation http://nginx.org/en/docs/configure.html, thats why im confusing.

Comment: Are you sure the page refers to the version you are building? If you used the version 1.13.1 mentioned in the guide I linked, the option was not included on [the page in the time](https://web.archive.org/web/20170615135345/http://nginx.org:80/en/docs/configure.html) when [1.13.1 was released](http://nginx.org/2017.html). If you are following another guide, please include the link.

Comment: For the record: The first archived version of [Building nginx from Sources](http://nginx.org/en/docs/configure.html) containing the `--with-http_xslt_module` option comes from [2018-04-29](https://web.archive.org/web/20180429093016/https://nginx.org/en/docs/configure.html).

Comment: @WimalWeerawansa Keep in mind if you're compiling NGINX you should always compile the most up to date version, especially if you're following the nginx.org docs data for config options.  You need to not use ancient NGINX, and use modern NGINX.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> `--builddir=nginx-1.9.9 \`

This suggests that you're using an **ancient** version of NGINX.  Use a newer version of the NGINX source code, because NGINX 1.9.x **did not have Dynamic Module Support for the XSLT module** in a way that was truly 'stable' compared to nowadays.  This might explain why you're getting the complaint about an invalid option.

The current Mainline version is 1.15.x, and current Stable is 1.14.x.  Use one of those versions, and that argument should work without issue.  (You absolutely under no circumstances should try using 1.9.9 to build dynamic modules, you should always use the most modern NGINX you can get your hands on)